# How to load default colums while loading parquet file in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am loading parquet file into snowflake using copy command. Parquet file has 10 column and Snowflake target table has 12 column( 2 with default dates - create  date and update date)

SQL compilation error: Insert value list does not match column list expecting 12 but got 10

Is there any way i can load default values into snowflake table while loading the data through parquet file with less or more colums

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please update your question with the DDL for the target table and the full copy command

Comment: COPY INTO TARGET_TABLE
FROM  ( SELECT 
$1:COL1::VARCHAR, 
$1:COL2::VARCHAR,
$1:COL3::VARCHAR, 
$1:COL4::VARCHAR
from
@STAGE/FOLDER/)  
pattern = '.*.03142022'  
file_format =(TYPE = PARQUET COMPRESSION = SNAPPY);


TARGET TABLE Structure:
COL 1 COL2 COL3 Col 4 CREATEDT UPDTDT

where 
"CREATE_DT" timestamp default  current_timestamp()
"UPDT_DT" timestamp default current_timestamp()

Answer (score -1):

You must give all columns in table specification.
If we use only copy into table_name from (select column_names from @stage), then stage file needs to match all column present in table.

```
copy into <table>(<col1>,<col2>,....<col10>) from 
(select 
$1:<col_1_parq_file>::<format_specifier>,
$1:<col_2_parq_file>::<format_specifier>,
$1:<col_3_parq_file>::<format_specifier>,
.
.
.
$1:<col_10_parq_file>::<format_specifier>
from @<stage_with_parquest_file>);
```